# Using HTML5 geolocation while posting a form in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, html

What I'm trying to do here is get the Geolocation of user (browser), use hidden fields to hold the lat and long, once form is posted (image uploaded), the lat and lon to be displayed back in the notice (will use them later in model to store them). The issue I'm having here is that I have to refresh a couple of times before posting to get the Lat,Long. Otherwise the form submits Nil values for both. Here is the relevant code I'm using:

app/assets/javascript/html5geolocatio.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
          onSuccess,
          onError, {
              enableHighAccuracy: true,
              timeout: 20000,
              maximumAge: 120000
          }
  );


function onSuccess(position) {
    myPosition[0] = position.coords.latitude;
    myPosition[1] = position.coords.longitude;
    document.getElementById("image_lon").value = position.coords.longitude;
    document.getElementById("image_lat").value = position.coords.latitude;
}

 function onError(err) {
    var message;

    switch (err.code) {
    case 0:
      message = 'Unknown error: ' + err.message;
      break;
    case 1:
      message = 'You denied permission to retrieve a position.';
      break;
    case 2:
      message = 'The browser was unable to determine a position: ' + error.message;
      break;
    case 3:
      message = 'The browser timed out before retrieving the position.';
      break;
    }
 }

});
```

Image Controller:

```
def create
    @photo = current_user.images.build(image_params)
    if @photo.save
        flash[:notice] = "Photo has been uploaded" + params[:image][:lat]+ ','  + params[:image][:lon] 
        redirect_to root_url
    else
        render 'static_pages/home'

    end
end
```

Upload Form:

```
<%= form_for @photo do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
<%= f.file_field :image %>
<%= f.hidden_field :lon %>
<%= f.hidden_field :lat %>
<%= f.submit "Upload Photo" %>
<% end %>
```

Also, if there's a better way to do this I'd appreciate it if you can let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like your form is posting before the user has taken action (allow/deny permission) to pull his/her location.

Comment: In addition to what André mentioned, `enableHighAccuracy` can introduce a significant (up to tens of seconds) fix delay.

Comment: You might also want to check the rendered HTML to verify your selectors are correct. If `@photo` isn't an `Image`, you won't have `image_*` form fields.

Comment: @AndréDion I am posting the form after allowing location (allowing the browser popup).
I also removed the Highaccuracy, still same, sadly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example on how to pass javascript variable to Rails app: https://github.com/lorenzosinisi/javascript-variable-to-rails-controller

You can write your variables into cookie and than access from your controllers like this:

In view (with javascript):

```
 document.cookie = "latitudine="+latitude;
 document.cookie = "longitudine="+longitude;
```

And in controller:

```
@latitudine_full = cookies[:latitudine].nil? ? '0.00' : cookies[:latitudine]
@longitudine_full = cookies[:longitudine].nil? ? '0.00' : cookies[:longitudine]
```

This will work when you reload the page.

If you want to clean/remove cookies after posting you can do that with javascript